# How to convert all "link rel stylesheet" relative path to absolute path in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

How I can convert all "link rel stylesheet"in html 's relative path to absolute path using javascript?

before

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sample.css">
```

thing i want

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sample.com/sample.css">
```

Comment: Please expand on your question. What do you mean by *convert*?

Comment: They're both absolute. It's just the first one is absolute to the web root folder...

Comment: What's the point of doing that? Do you want to absolutize using a custom base URI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `href` attribute with the `href` property value:

```
link.setAttribute("href", link.href); // won't work in old IE
```

, or set the `href` property as itself:

```
link.href = link.href; // maybe different for each browser
```